# Проблема с тегом nav

Tags: css3, html5, центрирование

у меня возникла проблема с nav. Я хочу его поставить по центру, чтобы кнопка "Войти" была сбоку. Помогите это сделать, пожалуйста!

```css
header{
 background: url(../img/first-fon.png) no-repeat center / cover;
 height: 724px;
}
div.container {
 width: 1030px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.first-h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 48px;
 text-align: center;
}
.logo {
 float: left;
}
div.menu {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 940px;
 padding: 50px;
}
a.text-menu {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
nav.menu {
 float: right;
}
nav.menu ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;

}
nav.menu ul li {
 float: left;
 display:block;
 margin-right: 50px;
}
a.button {
 display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: lowercase;
   padding: 9px 22px;
   outline: none;
   border: 1px solid rgb(250,172,17);
   border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(255,212,3) -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(255,212,3), rgb(248,157,23));
    background: rgb(255,212,3) -o-linear-gradient(rgb(255,212,3), rgb(248,157,23));
    background: rgb(255,212,3) linear-gradient(rgb(255,212,3), rgb(248,157,23));
   box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,0,0);
   transition: box-shadow .2s, border-color .2s;
}
a.button:hover {
 transition: all 3s ease;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #f8f29d;
}
a.button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), inset 0 0 0 60px rgba(255,255,0,.45);
}
div.login {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="menu">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      <nav class="menu">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="#" class="text-menu">Услуги</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" class="text-menu">Преимущества</a></li>
        <li>
         <a href="#" class="text-menu">Контакты</a>
        </li> 
       </ul>
       <div class="login">
        <a href="login.html" class="button">Войти</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <h1 class="first-h1">ВЗРЫВНОЕ ПРОДВИЖЕНИЕ <br>В СОЦИАЛЬНЫХ СЕТЯХ<h1>
  </div>
 </header>
```

введите сюда код

Comment: используйте flex-box для подобных целей

Comment: `nav.menu ul` и `div.login` задайте им `display:inline-block;` зачем задавать блочное отображение тому, что и так уже блочное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

блок с классом .login вынесите на один уровень с nav, далее блоку с классом .menu задайте display: flex; justify-content: space-between; Задаем ширину блоку nav, а также display: flex; justify-content: space-between; как и у родительского блока